# Issue with removing divs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make simple memory game, but first I must create the board which should contains tiles. When I delete any div, I want the free space after it to remain in place. Unfortunately after deletion, all divs move. I know that it will be necessary to use absolute positioning for each div here, but I have no idea how to do it.

```
<body>
  <div class="board-container">

  </div>

</body>

html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  background-color: white !important;
  p {
    color: black;
    font-size:10rem;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .board-container {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background-color: red;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
    p {
      font-size:2rem;
    }
    .board-tile {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border:1px solid black;
      background-color: yellow;
      display: inline-block;
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
    }
  }
}

function drawBoard(col, row) {
  var tile = ('<div class="board-tile"></div>');
  for(var i=0 ; i< row ; i++ ) {
    for (var j=0 ; j<col ; j++) {

      $('.board-container').append(tile);


    }
      $('.board-container').append('<br />')
  }

}

      drawBoard(5, 4);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6r67ceka/4/

Comment: Sounds like you want css visibility:hidden, or?

Comment: I noticed you have a syntax error on the `var tile = ('div...` line. It should be `var tile = $('div...`. In addition, you'll want to move your `tile` variable inside the inner for-loop, this will instantiate a new `tile` element for each run. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ake7v5nr/1/

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Technically, that's not an error. The plain JavaScript string is passed to the JQuery `.append()` method later as it should be. The extra parenthesis don't have any effect. You can see it working fine in my answer below.

Comment: @ScottMarcus oh! I was thinking OP was creating a new jQuery element. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't delete the `div`s, just change their CSS `opacity` property so that they are transparent. Do this by simply adding a pre-made class as seen below when you click a square.

```js
function drawBoard(col, row) {
  var tile = ('<div class="board-tile"></div>');
  for(var i=0 ; i< row ; i++ ) {
    for (var j=0 ; j<col ; j++) {
      $('.board-container').append(tile);
    }
    $('.board-container').append('<br />')
  }
}
    
drawBoard(5, 4);

$(".board-tile").on("click", function(){
  $(this).addClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
/* This class will be added to any clicked div, causing
   it to no longer be visible, but still take up space. */
.hidden { opacity:0; }

html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  background-color: white !important;
}

p {
    color: black;
    font-size:10rem;
    text-align:center;
}

.board-container {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background-color: red;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
}

p {
      font-size:2rem;
}

.board-tile {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border:1px solid black;
      background-color: yellow;
      display: inline-block;
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="board-container"></div>
```

Comment: I like your answer +1 but the original question was about removing a div.

Comment: @GibboK That's the point, if you remove the `div`, you are going to reflow the document, resulting in the shifting of the rest of the `div`s. There is no solution that removes the divs because something would have to put back in its place.

Comment: Yes I got your point, but in the original question, OP was asking how to remove div and how to do it. I worked out that problem in my answer. Anyway...  I hope could be useful :) Thank for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the coordinates of your tile using `position: absolute` and `top` & `left` doing some basic math in your loop.

Notes1: this solution answers question removing the div, as from original question, but IMO Scott Marcus's approach using opacity is the only solution if you do not use position absolute.

Notes2: In your original version you were touching the DOM each time per loop, unfortunately this approach it is quite expensive. In the following version instead I create HTML in a string and attach it to the DOM only once.

Example:

```js
let drawBoard = (columns, rows) => {
  let html = '';
  let topInc = 50;
  let top = 0;
  let leftInc = 50;
  let left = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    top += topInc;
    for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      left += leftInc;
      let tile = `<div id="${i}${j}" class="board-tile" style="position: absolute; top: ${top}px; left: ${left}px;">${i}${j}</div>`;
      html += tile;
    }
    left = 0;
  }
  $('.board-container').append(html);
};

drawBoard(5, 4);

$('#02').remove();
$('#11').remove();
```

```css
.board-tile {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="board-container">
  </div>
</body>
```